# TFS Build and absolute path in app.config

Tags: build, tfs, path, tfsbuild

first, I'd like to apologize for my english, it's not my 1st language ! 
I'm a total n00b in the wonderful world of TFS Build (2010), and I've got a problem.
I'll try to explain it to you using a simple example (but my actual situation is much more complicated).

I have a project with a console application "MyApp1", its location on my computer is "D:\MyProjets\MyApp1".
I have another project "Res" which contains only resources, including a file named emailTemplate.html.

My project "MyApp1" uses this file. Therefore, in the "App.config" file there's a key that stores the path of this resource : "D:\MyProjets\Res\emailTemplate.html"

Finally, I have a test for that application "MyApp1".  This test checks if an e-mail has been sent. To send the e-mail "MyApp1" will need the file "emailTemplate.html", and will use the key in the configuration file to find it.

When I run the test on my computer : everything's ok.

But if I build the solution with TFS Build, when the tests are run I have a problem with this resource. During the build, the source files are copied in a directory (for example  "D:\Build\1\My build projet\Sources\MyProjets\Res", and therefore "MyApp1" will look for  "emailTemplate.html" in "D:\MyProjets\Res\emailTemplate.html" (configuration file) and of course won't be able to find it.

How should I do ?

I already know that my project shouldn't work with resources this way, but it's almost impossible for us to change that now, since it's the way we've been working in my company for a loooong time...

I thought about modifying the BuildProcessTemplate to force the Build server to run a getLatest on the Res projects exactly where I want. But I don't know if it's a good idea, or if it's even possible...

Thanks a lot for your help ! :)

Answer (score 1):

Edit your build definition to include the "Res" project directory in the workspace as well. It should be automatically download/updated at each build (if you use any of the default process templates), and as long as you use relative paths in your tests you should be fine.

Comment: I still have problems while using relative paths. Therefore I modified the process template file : right after the 'Get workspace' task I added a task that copies the needed resources in a specified directory.